# SetterBar behavior

Tags: gui-construction, interface, user-interface

**Preamble**

Consider a [`SetterBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetterBar.html):

```
SetterBar[1, StringRepeat["q", #] & /@ Range@5]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

That is with vertical layout:

```
SetterBar[1, StringRepeat["q", #] & /@ Range@5, Appearance -> "Vertical"]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Two things are different:

First, the unpressed buttons look differently in vertical than in horizontal layout, because the vertical layout has a mouse-over behavior, which horizontal layout doesn't.

> [image: Blockquote]

Second, the buttons are nicely aligned by the width of the longest element, but when you click one more time on the already selected button, it shrinks to the length of the string.

> [image: Blockquote]

I tried to construct a setter bar myself, using [`Setter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Setter.html):

```
Column[Setter[Dynamic@x, #, StringRepeat["q", #]] & /@ Range@5]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Looks normal now (no mouse-over behavior), but the same story with the button changing its appearance when double clicked. Apparently, we can use [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html) to fix this:

```
Column[Setter[Dynamic@x, #, StringRepeat["q", #], ImageSize -> 100] & /@ Range@5]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

I thought I can port this to [`SetterBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetterBar.html), and it works, but the FE complains that the [`ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageSize.html)is not a valid option for `SetterBar`:

```
SetterBar[1, StringRepeat["q", #] & /@ Range@5, 
    Appearance -> "Vertical", ImageSize -> 100]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Also, the buttons seem to be next to each other, not like in the column of `Setter`s, so I added [`ImageMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMargins.html), and it works again, but the FE doens't like it either:

```
SetterBar[1, StringRepeat["q", #] & /@ Range@5, 
    Appearance -> "Vertical", ImageSize -> 100, 
    ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {5, 0}}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Also, the appearance is still "mouse-over" like.

**Questions:**

1) What happens with [`SetterBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetterBar.html)when I change the layout from horizontal to vertical? Why the appearance of the buttons changes to "mouse-over"? Can we control it?

2) Why the FE complains about options for `SetterBar` that work fine? Is this a normal behavior? Is this is bug? Are the other examples of the similar behavior?

Comment: This is not a well-focused question. It jumps around asking a number of different questions about the behavior of Setter and SetterBar. You seem to want someone to write a treatise on how these controls work -- and on more than one OS as well. I could give a work around for the problem you start with, the strange (and I think buggy) behavior of SetterBar when double-clicked. But why bother since it's only one tiny part of a multipart question, and I am not prepared to tackle the whole shebang

Comment: I don't seem to have the same trouble with V11.1.1 on a Mac.

Comment: @m_goldberg Well, the intention was to give a background, and of course I could ask few smaller questions. I thought it would be good for people to read, because this site is also about information sharing, not just Q&A style. Correct me if this is wrong. If I have to pick, I would pick the one about incorrect FE behavior parsing options (which is also how I would fix the double-clicked behavior). This is truly annoying. Others are mostly platform specific. Should I make a new question?

Comment: Not sure I understand "too broad" and "not sure what you are asking" close votes -- I asked three structured questions (and I deleted one to make it even more explicit), now there are two questions. What is broad here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To keep button size, one option would be to add `StringPadRight`

```
SetterBar[1, StringPadRight @ ( StringRepeat["q", #] & /@ Range@5 ), 
Appearance -> {"Vertical", "Button"}]
```

[image]

To diminish margins one possible way is to add "AbuttingLeft", i.e.

```
 SetterBar[1, StringPadRight @ ( StringRepeat["q", #] & /@ Range@5 ), 
 Appearance -> {"Vertical", "AbuttingLeft"}]
```

[image]

As a trade-off, one more documented option is to use `Appearance->"Palette"`.

[image]

Also notice that at my Mac OS with V10.3 `"Horizontal"` appearance behaves in the same way (with small move of the right side of double-clicked buttons).

[image]

---

For `Manipulate` it is also possible to use `ImageSize` and `Alignment` via `Row` like so:

```
Manipulate[s,
{{s, 1}, (# -> 
  Row[{#}, ImageSize -> 39, Alignment -> Center]) & /@ 
 (StringRepeat["q", #] & /@ Range@5), SetterBar, Appearance -> "Vertical"}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

@MichaelE2's warning concerning size parameters applies here as well.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `Pane` to solve such alignment problems.  String padding in a variable-width font does not produce reliable results, and `Pane` can be used to get around that.  (Fortunately or unfortunately, a vertical `SetterBar` automatically pads out the buttons to be the same sizes, and I cannot check this on Windows.)

One of the issues is to determine the dimensions to use for `Pane`.  In particular, the width depends on the style in which the `SetterBar` is ultimately displayed.  When the style is unknown, it can be a challenge to get it right.  Usually, I don't worry if the dimensions are little too large, and estimate by trial and error. However, sometimes one wants to get it exactly right, or at least exactly the same as something else.  For that one can apply `Rasterize` to the string in the display style.

```
strings = StringRepeat["q", #] & /@ Range@5;
width = First@Rasterize[#, "BoundingBox"] & /@ strings // Max
(*  39  *)

SetterBar[1, Pane[#, width, Alignment -> Center] & /@ strings, Appearance -> {"Vertical"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For another style, do this:

```
style = "Label";
width = First@Rasterize[Style[#, style], "BoundingBox"] & /@ styledstrings // Max
(*  28  *)

SetterBar[1, Pane[#, width, Alignment -> Center] & /@ strings, Appearance -> {"Vertical"},
 BaseStyle -> style]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For a `Manipulate` setter bar, use the `"ManipulateLabel"` style:

```
style = "ManipulateLabel";
width = First@Rasterize[Style[#, style], "BoundingBox"] & /@ styledstrings // Max
(*  27  *)

Manipulate[
 s,
 {{s, "q"}, # -> Pane[#, width, Alignment -> Center] & /@ strings, 
  SetterBar, Appearance -> {"Vertical"}, ControlPlacement -> Left}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can compare the width with the default `Manipulate`, or with other values for `width`, with

```
Grid[List /@ {man1, man2,...}, Spacings -> 0, 
 Dividers -> {{1 -> Thin, 2 -> Thin}, None}]
```

Below are the widths in the `"ManipulateLabel"` style of the strings padded with spaces.  They vary considerably.

```
First@Rasterize[Style[#, style], "BoundingBox"] & /@ 
 StringPadRight@(StringRepeat["q", #] & /@ Range@5)
(*  {15, 19, 21, 25, 27}  *)
```

For a fixed-width font, there is no such problem.

```
First@Rasterize[#, "BoundingBox"] & /@ 
 StringPadRight@(StringRepeat["q", #] & /@ Range@5)
(*  {39, 39, 39, 39, 39}  *)
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the OP's remarks "appearance is still 'mouse-over'" and "`AutoAction` option doesn't work here naturally, as this is about automatic push, not the appearance," or I would try to address them.  There is no `Appearance` "mouse-over."  `AutoAction` works (naturally), but perhaps the OP means it is not desired.  In that case `AutoAction -> False` works (or should as it does on my computer).

Comment: Thank you! You are right. This is actually not relevant as I understand it now -- I just thought the `AutoAction` is responsible for changing the shape of the buttons when the mouse cursor is over, but obviously it is not what we need for this. Will edit the question now.